# usage of ''there ''in a sentence

Tags: grammar

> Off they went to look for him in the forest,
>   and there atop a tall bael tree  was their friend, sitting tight.

In this sentence, what does "there" refer to, "atop a tall bael tree" or "in the forest"?

Comment: Which do you think it refers to and why?

Comment: @learner Did you see the way Peter fixed your punctuation? Take a close look at what he did!

Comment: @P.E.Dant I'm wondering if the problem is not self-correcting keyboards inserting that space before punctuation marks. Mine sometimes puts spaces in weird places.

Comment: In thise case , what does 'there ' work .?

Comment: @AlanCarmack That's possible, maybe, but this quirk seems so widespread that it's hard to imagine that's the reason. As far as I know, no written language uses the comma surrounded by spaces, but maybe learner's does.

Comment: @learner Are you typing on a phone, tablet, or computer keyboard? Because you keep inserting a space before a period and before a comma, and a space does not go in either place.

Comment: I'd say it was a pro-form that is anaphoric to the PP "in the forest". Preposed locative complements like this occur in subject-dependent constructions, cf. the non-preposed "Their friend was there, sitting tight atop a tall bael tree".

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's take each phrase out of the sentence and see if what remains makes sense.

> 1 Off  they went to look for him in the forest, and there was their friend, sitting tight.

In sentence 1,  *there* does not have to  refer to  *in the forest*. *They* went *in(to) the forest.* He sat tight. He could be miles away, in the city. I think this would be an existential there.

For *there* to refer to *in the forest*, I might expect

> 1b Off  they went to look for him in the forest, and their friend  was there, sitting tight.

Now consider the sentence without *in the forest*:

> 2  Off they went to look for him,  and there atop a tall bael tree was their friend, sitting tight.

In Sentence 2, *there* refers to *atop a tall bael tree*.

So, to me, the meaning doesn't change when you have the complete sentence:

> Off they went to look for him in the forest, and there atop a tall bael tree was their friend, sitting tight.

*There* still refers to *atop a tall bael tree*. Of course the tree is 'in the forest', but we have seen that if we remove 'in the forest'  *there* refers to *atop a tall bael tree*.

Notice [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/there)

> there
>
> 1 In, at, or to that place or position

Opinions may vary on this one.

Comment: I'd say that "there" is a pro-form anaphoric to the PP "in the forest". I'd analyse this as a subject-dependent inversion construction in which "there" is a preposed locative complement. (cf the non-preposed "Their friend was there, sitting tight atop a tall bael tree", where "there" means "in the forest").